# lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js causes sliders crash

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I added lightbox to master page, it works but it caused to crash slider. When I remove

```
<script src="~/***/js/dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

line, slider works but lightbox doesn't work at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I think ***lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js*** contains required *jquery* codes too. I already call jquery library another place so ***plus-jquery*** definition is extra and unnecessary. Finally I found some .js files in **js** folder under the **lightbox directory** (../dist/js) and changed **lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js** definition as **lightbox.min.js**. It worked.